# Apache storm and kafka: how can I get the consumer object of a kafka spout such that I can log its offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm using apache storm-core 0.9.6 (it's old, can't do nothing about it due to legacy) `KafkaSpout`. If I can log the tuple offset, then it would be very helpful for me to debug some deserialization issue I'm facing.

So far I've seen that `storm.kafka.KafkaUtils` has 2 methods:

```
public static long getOffset(SimpleConsumer consumer, String topic, int partition, KafkaConfig config) 
public static long getOffset(SimpleConsumer consumer, String topic, int partition, long startOffsetTime)
```

where the first is a wrapper around the 2nd one. It seems to me that the only thing I don't know how to get to call this function is the `consumer`. I've read the `KafkaSpout` code and have not been able to figure out how to get the kafka consumer from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the storm-kafka code, you can do whatever logging you need after the point where the messages are fetched https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v0.9.6/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/PartitionManager.java#L162. You can build the modified version of storm-kafka yourself and point your build tool at your own copy.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll read the code and see if I can figure it out.